# Same store on multiple component

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

in my app I have `user.component` and `college.component`.
In `user.component` with `store` i get users list

```
this.store.dispatch(new LoadUsers());
this.users$ = this.store.select(UserSelector.getAllUsers)
this.users$.subscribe(...)
```

And on `college.component` I also need this user from store, and I call same dispatch

```
this.store.dispatch(new LoadUsers());
this.users$ = this.store.select(UserSelector.getAllUsers)
this.users$.subscribe(...)
```

I call the same `this.store.dispatch(new LoadUsers());` because, if I on first page load open college page, I don't have users in store, and I need to call them.

If I first open `users.component` I get users but when I after going on college page
I get error

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined 
>   for users.

What is the best way in this case to handle store like this?

Check if data exist in store and call dispatch or make same action/reducer/effect for `loadUsers()` for every component??

Thnx

Comment: What is bad with loading users twice? Imagine the users changed on server-side in the time you switch between the components.

Comment: You are correct, that's why i ask for advice

Comment: Go with your solution as is. I think that is totally fine. Just an additional advice: don't forget to unsubscribe

Comment: Do you mean from users or?

Comment: Yes. If you only assign the variable in subscription prefer to not subscribe ans use async pipe instead. Then you don't need to care about unsubscribing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user data changes a lot, it's ok to reload. If your user data is quite static, which it normally would be, it's not wise to make that call multiple times because it just makes your app slower for no reason.

To tackle the single loading, there's two ways of doing it. you should hold a loaded parameter on your entity and then on load success put that loaded value to true in the reducer.

You can now subscribe to that loaded value, if it's false dispatch the load, if it's true don't dispatch the call. This route keeps the effects simpler but your containers will have longer/uglier code.

```js
constructor(private store: Store<fromAuth.State & fromData.State>){
  this.users$ = this.store.select(UserSelector.getAllUsers);
}


ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select(UserSelector.getUsersLoaded).subscribe(value => 
    if (!value) this.store.dispatch(new LoadUsers());
  );
}
```

A smoother way is to keep your code as is and do this check in the effect. *(replied to me by Duncan Hunter on Pluralsights course on ngrx)* ([ref. to ngrx course on pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-ngrx-getting-started/table-of-contents))

1. Component loads and subscribe to the store variable where the data might or will be.
2. Dispatch the action on ngOnInit to load the data.
3. In an effect check if store has the data and maybe if it is older than a certain time. I try my best to only check the store in effect as little as possible as it makes them more complicated but in real projects I often have 6-12 effects like this.
4. If no data or stale call http to load but if it is already loaded I then dispatch an action like {type: 'entityXLoadedFromStore'}; Which does not do anything but add a log message into the system to be able to see it was loaded from the store.

This route keeps your code cleaner in the containers, but makes the effects complex.

Both routes are viable, you can choose which you prefer.

I'd like to reference to the [fantastic demo](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/projects/example-app/src/app) app given by the NGRX team as well, which is a great source of inspiration for ngrx methods. (However they don't address your question in there).

Answer (score 1):

**What will be the point of using store if you are doing the API call twice for the same entity?**

According to me, you should not call the users API twice. You should keep less no of API calls as possible to provide the customer very light and efficient user experience.

For this I would recommend adding `loaded` and `loading` two new fields in your state and then create a selector `isInitialised` like this:

```js
export const getUsersInitialised = (state: State) => state.loaded || state.loading;
```

then load users only if either the users are not loaded or any other component is already loading them like so,

```js
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  const users = this.store.select(getAllUsers);

  this.store.select(getUsersInitialised).pipe(take(1), filter(v => !v)).subscribe(() => {
    this.store.dispatch(new LoadUsers());
  });

  return users;
}
```

This way, users API will be called only once when users are not loaded and once they are loaded, every time users will be returned from store itself.

**NOTE** -

- Initially **loading** and **loaded** will be false.
- Make sure to update the user in store also, if you are editing the user from frontend.
- In your **LoadUsers action**, make sure you change the **loading** state of users to `true`
- In your **API response**, make sure you change the **loaded** state of users to `true` and loading state to `false`.

Comment: But you will then never have uptodate-data for longer sessions. But in general of course keep request amount small.